# CLLocationCoordinate2D Latitude and Longitude NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mapkit

I am trying to set my MapKit View latitude and longitude to values from NSStrings. Although when I try do set them I get the error:

```
Assigning to 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'double') from incompatible type 'NSString *_ strong'
```

Below is my code

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;

zoomLocation.latitude = latitudevariable;
zoomLocation.longitude = longitudevariable;
```

Both variables are NSStrings

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is wrong. It says you are trying to assign a string to a double. In virtually all programming languages you can't assign completely different types to each other. You need to covert the string to a double. Use NSString's doubleValue to do that.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of code as to how to do that? I'm pretty new to objective-c

Comment: zoomLocation.latitude = [latitudevariable doubleValue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I changed my variables to this

```
zoomLocation.latitude = [latitudevariable doubleValue];
zoomLocation.longitude = [longitudevariable doubleValue];
```